# Need to identify number that is higher than a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a date column in a table. The date column is in varchar. I want to identify a particular date range  from that date column. My query is like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [003 AccptReg].[dbo].[SysData1]
WHERE [RegDate_Sys] > '18 jul 2013'
```

But the result is not giving accurate result, i.e. it gives dates which are prior of 18 jul 2013.

Is there any thing wrong I am doing?

Comment: **Don't store dates as strings (varchar, and the likes).** The DB does not know that it is a date. No, it won't "find it out by magic", and hence it will compare them as strings, entirely lexicographically. I recommend a restructuring of the schema...

Comment: List to others about not storing date in varchar, there are datatype in SQL Server to handle Date and DateTime. For now you can try `WHERE CAST([RegDate_Sys] as DATE) > CAST('18 jul 2013' AS DATE)`

Comment: "The date column is in varchar .... Is there any thing wrong I am doing?". Yes storing dates as `varchar`.

Comment: @CHHIBIAMOR - SQL Server per the tags. But knowing version would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the date as a `varchar`, and doesn't convert it to a date when you are doing the comparison. The database doesn't know that you see the data as dates, and will simply compare them as strings, so for example `'2 jan 1736'` will be larger than `'18 jul 2013'` because `2` comes after `1`.

The best would be if you could store the data as `datetime` values (or `date`), then you don't need to do the conversion when you compare the values, which would give better performance.

If that's not possible, do the conversion in the query:

```
select * from [003 AccptReg].[dbo].[SysData1]
where convert(datetime, [RegDate_Sys], 106) > '18 jul 2013'
```

Depending on the settings on the server, you might also need to convert `'18 jul 2013'` in the same way for the database to understand it correctly as a date.

Answer (score 2):

For date column, you should compare as **DATE**

```
select * from [003 AccptReg].[dbo].[SysData1]
where CAST([RegDate_Sys] AS DATE) > CAST('18 jul 2013' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to datetime format and then compare:

```
 select * from [003 AccptReg].[dbo].[SysData1]
 where convert(datetime,[RegDate_Sys]) >convert(datetime,'18 jul 2013')
```